# ISRC or UPC available as lookup parameter or response element?

Tags: beatsmusic

Is it possible to do track and album lookups with params like ISRC or UPC on Beats Music?

Alternatively have ISRC / UPC as response elements when fetching a specific track, artist or album.

Case in sample for lookup: https://api.deezer.com/2.0/track/isrc:USWB11200587

Thanks

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to lookup tracks and albums by UPC or ISRC is not available on the public API at this time.

Comment: Thanks @DuchessSF

Is it possible to get access to a non-public API then?

We're experiencing increased demand for linking directly to tracks and albums on Beats music. Currently our matches are based on general meta data, which is not optimal.

If you can help, please drop me an e-mail on le@linkfire.com

Thanks.

Comment: @LarsWibergEttrup - I sent you a message from our support portal. This isn't available, yet, but I did forward this to the group for potential additions.